# Win7 2018-09 Quality Rollup (KB4457144) fails with 0x8000FFFF error

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

When I try to install KB4457144 ([2018-09 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177467/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp)), installation stops, no matter from Windows Update or downloading from Catalog and running it.

Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: try to install KB 3177467 at first, then install KB4457144 again.

Comment: That's my answer. Just documenting how I got to solve my problem. Answering your question (provided is a valuable information and it doesn't exist in any KB in SE) [is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). I found that many people was in my case and the answer was not easy to point, that's why I made this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to install it in [this post from AskWoody](https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/reported-error-0x8000ffff-with-the-win7-monthly-rollup-kb-4457144/#post-217071) by **Pradeep Dixit**, among a load of reports.

> Patch KB4457144 will be installed after installing Stack Update
> “Servicing stack update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2
> SP1 – Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 – KB3177467 (x64)” for 2008 R2 OS

You must go to [Servicing stack update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1: September 20, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177467/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp), download the appropriate version for your system and install it.

Be aware that this update has known issues

> **Restart stuck on "Stage 2 of 2" or "Stage 3 of 3"**
>
> After you install
> update 3177467 together with other updates, a restart may be required
> to complete the installation. During this restart, you may find
> yourself stuck on "Stage 2 of 2" or "Stage 3 of 3".
>
> If you encounter this issue, press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to continue to log
> on. This should occur only one time and does not prevent updates from
> installing successfully.
>
> Note In managed environments, such as by using Windows Server Update
> Services (WSUS), you can avoid either of these issues by deploying
> this update as a stand-alone update.

I needed no restart and I could install the 2018-09 SMQR flawlessly.